# c# ConvertFromUtc method - getting error

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I have the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt = ConvertFromUtc(DateTime.Now);
}

public DateTime ConvertFromUtc(DateTime dt)
{
    var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(Session["Timezone"].ToString());           
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, tz);
}
```

I am getting the following message:

> *The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime did not have the Kind property set correctly.  For example, when the
>   Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be
>   TimeZoneInfo.Local. Parameter name: sourceTimeZone.*

I tried to add the following but that did not help:

```
    DateTime dateTimeToConvert = new DateTime(dt, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```

Comment: That code doesn't make sense. If you want the current local time, get `DateTime.Now`. If you want the current UTC time, get `DateTime.UtcNow`. But converting a local time from UTC is ... meaningless. You're getting the error because `DateTime.Now` is not a UTC time.

Comment: Also have a look at the ToUniversalTime() and ToLocalTime() functions of your DateTime object.

Comment: Buy the .NET designers a cigar for keeping you out of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`

Comment: I am trying to go from the a date that is UTC and trying to get the local date.